# Do I cover all possible scenarios in this basic maths & subtraction Python script?

Tags: python, math, addition, subtraction

I'm currently learning maths through Khan Academy and I'm creating a program in Python's IDLE to give me randomized questions so that I can practice maths. So far I've just done addition and subtraction and would like to check that I'm covering all possible sum scenarios under 7 digits (9999999). This is the basic addition script:

```
def one_digit_addition():
    counter = 0
    target = 5

    while counter < target:
        random_digit_one = random.randint(0, 9)
        random_digit_two = random.randint(0, 9)

        print "What is %s + %s?" % (random_digit_one, random_digit_two)
        answer = random_digit_one + random_digit_two
        userAnswer = int(raw_input("Answer: "))
        if userAnswer == answer:
            counter = counter + 1
            print "\n*CORRECT*, your score is %s. Next question...\n" % counter

        elif userAnswer != answer:
            counter = counter - 5
            print "\n*INCORRECT*! Your score is %s. Next question...\n" % counter


        if counter == 5:
        print "**CONGRATULATIONS, you've passed one digit addition. Now loading two digit addition...**\n"
            two_digit_addition()
```

After this one_digit_addition function I have functions of the copied code above going right up to seven digit addition. The only difference is is that I've added an extra 9 to both the random integer variables each time. Here's the subtraction script:

```
def one_digit_subtraction():
    counter = 0
    target = 5

    while counter < target:
        random_digit_one = random.randint(0,9)
        random_digit_two = random.randint(0,9)

        if random_digit_one > random_digit_two:
            print "What is %s - %s?" % (random_digit_one, random_digit_two)
            answer = random_digit_one - random_digit_two
        else:
            print "What is %s - %s?" % (random_digit_two, random_digit_one)
            answer = random_digit_two - random_digit_one

        userAnswer = int(raw_input("Answer: "))
        if userAnswer == answer:
            counter = counter + 1
            print "\n*CORRECT*, your score is %s. Next question...\n" % counter

        elif userAnswer != answer:
            counter = counter - 5
            print "\n*INCORRECT*! Your score is %s. Next question...\n" % counter

        if counter == 5:
             print "**CONGRATULATIONS, you've passed one digit subtraction. Now loading two digit subtraction...**\n"
             two_digit_subtraction()
```

It's the same for this script. I've copied the code and added a 9 integer to the number variables. My main concern is that I'm missing out certain sums with this current formula. I basically would like there to be a chance of there being every possible sum combination <= 999999999. I hope this question was worded better than my last one.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Are these basic Python maths scripts correct?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21711167/are-these-basic-python-maths-scripts-correct)

Comment: You have 7 different functions that do this logic, only varying the randInt(0,#)? Why not create one function that you call, pass a parameter to say what your maximum is, and then use that number to generate your randInt from? It would save a lot of code duplication, and allow you to vary your ranges a bit more. Something like digit_subtraction(9), would give 0-9, digit_subtraction(99) would give 0-99, etc.

Just a friendly comment/suggestion.

Comment: Yeah I've been thinking how stupid the code duplication is. Can you explain a little more how it would vary my range though?

Answer (score 1):

Try to parametrise your function in order to avoid the repetitions.

For instance with this:

```
import random
import operator

ops = {'+' : operator.add, '-': operator.sub, '*': operator.mul}

def quiz (operator, digits):
    start = 10 ** (digits - 1) if digits > 1 else 0
    a = random.randint (start, 10 ** digits - 1)
    b = random.randint (start, 10 ** digits - 1)
    if operator == '-' and a < b: a, b = b, a
    r = input ('What is {} {} {}? '.format (a, operator, b) )
    try: return int (r) == ops [operator] (a, b)
    except ValueError: return False
```

You can ask for a 2-digit addition with `quiz('+', 2)` for a three digit subtraction with `quiz('-', 3)` or for a 1-digit multiplication with `quiz('*', 1)`. In each case the function returns `True` iff the user answered correctly.

---

For python2 replace `input` with `raw_input`.

Comment: Thanks for this although it seems quite advanced for someone of my level lol. It's amazing how you've got the three different operations in such a small amount of code though. Something to aim for.